# mysql table update with last value

Tags: mysql

i have two table

table1:

```
 id  |        time              |  value
----------------------------------------
 1   |  2024-01-09 22:24:14     |   100
----------------------------------------
 2   |  2024-01-10 22:25:14     |   200
----------------------------------------
 3   |  2024-01-11 22:26:14     |   300
----------------------------------------
```

table2:

```
id    |   last_value
----------------------
 1    |   ---
----------------------
```

i need to update table2.lastvalue with table1 last recede (2024-01-11 22:26:14 recode value 300)

how can i do that?

i try below script

```
update Table1, Table2 set Table2.last_value = Table1.Value where Table2.Id=1;
```

But every time update in first recede (100)

Comment: How is PHP related? Can you please add more details? Not clear what "every time update in first recede (100)" is trying to say.

Comment: You should not use comma joins. That is from the 90s. Use `join` syntax and define the relationship between the 2 tables with `on`. You also can use aliases so dou dont need to type out the full table name every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most recent `table1.value` row you can `` ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1 ``:

```sql
UPDATE table2
SET `last_value` = (SELECT value FROM table1 ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4W2bBKjj).

Storing this redundant data is unlikely to provide any benefit over having an index on `` (`time`, `value`) ``. There is almost certainly a better method, depending on your specific use case.